# L is a regular language. Is $L' = \{a^{|w|} : w \in L\} $ a regular language?

Tags: automata, formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

Let $ L \subseteq  \{a,b\}^*$ be a regular language.

Is $L' = \{ {a^{|w|} : w \in L} \}$ a regular language?

We tried to define a function $f$ such that $f(r)=r'$ so that $ L(r')=L'$ but we couldn't develop it into something useful.

Will appriciate any hint or directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use complete induction on $|r|$. When $|r| = 1$ easily find a regular expression $r'$ such that defines $L'$. Then assume for any $|r|<n$ that a regular expression $r'$ exists, such that defines $L'$. And finally, prove for $|r| = n$.

1. There exists $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that $r = ((r_1)\cup(r_2))$.
2. There exists $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that $r = ((r_1)\circ(r_2))$.
3. There exists $r_1$ such that $r = (r_1)^*$.

Those are the three cases $r$ can be built using regular expressions with a smaller length than $n$, and then the assumption can be used.

P.S: If you're from BGU, which I think you are, look at practical session 2, last exercise, very similar.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Let $M$ be a DFA that accepts $L$. Modify $M$ to get an NFA that accepts $L'$.

Comment: Is there a way of proving this theory without using automats?

Comment: @mathftw Yes, in principle at least, you can always translate a proof using automata theory to one that does not. But the resulting proof may well be long and tedious, not to mention totally unenlightening. (Not saying whether that is necessarily the case here. I haven't looked very hard.)

Comment: @mathftw: Regular languages are closed under string homomorphisms; if you know that result, you can use it instead of automata. But automata give an extremely easy proof.